# How to set dynamic column width to AG-Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to set column width dynamically. That's mean here has attached stackblitz example. According to that example when i change the screen size only change table border. There not change Column width!|

I want to change column width also chanage with the table!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-kinvv8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```css
    remove position form app.component.html relative;left: 25% 
    and rpelace style="width: 100%; height: 220px
```

Comment: Thank for trying! But is's not work. Right side width is fit to the screen but content is not change!

Comment: i have another solution for you. you use java script re size function

Comment: with if else method like this $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: var width =  $("table").width();  go to console.log(width) then call resize function with if else like if (width<1300){}

Comment: if(width<1300px){ $(border).css("border","1px solid gray")}else{$(border).css("border","1px solid red")} not that if you know that method then this help full for you otherwise sorry brother!

Comment: it is very easy i'm sharing code with you $( window ).resize(function() {
  sidenavContentWidth = (sidenavContent.style.width).replace('px','')
  if(sidenavContentWidth > 0){
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if(windowWidth < 501){
  sidenavContent.style.width = "300px";
  }else{
  sidenavContent.style.width = "400px";
  }
  }
});

Comment: this is my own navigation  bar code on resize function you just add your setting  here in if else like $('.table').css("border"," 1px solid red"); else{$("table").css("border"," 1px solid gray")} okay i think now you completely understand other wise tomorrow i have free time for you......